# Setting div's or sections to the size of the viewport

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm having trouble doing this using css/javascript I want to set a number of sections of the page to the exact height and width of the browser window. If they adjust the browser window id like the sections to adjust as well. What I'm looking for is a similar effect to this

http://adamrudzki.com/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('section').css('minHeight',$(window).height() + 'px');
});
```

CSS

```
section{width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    calculateSectionContainerHeight();
});

$(document).ready(function (){
    calculateSectionContainerHeight();
});

 // function to calculate section container height
 function calculateSectionContainerHeight() {

     var docHeight =  $(document).height();  

     // setting the section container height.
     $('#section-container').height(sectionHeight + "px");
  }
```

CSS

```
#section-container {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: @bach3 If you find **any** of the answers useful please **upvote it** and if answer is correct then 
please **accept it** this will help to remove the question from the list of **unanswered list of question**